# Jquery изменить только текущий $('span').text()

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Здравствуйте, есть n div'ов, которые находятся на одной странице и идут друг за другом с подобным кодом:

```
<div class="main">
 <span class="price">280</span>
 <select class="target">
   <option value="280">25</option>
   <option value="380">33</option>
 </select>
 <a href="#" onclick="js(option.text(), option.val())"></a>
</div>
```

Необходимо менять $('.price').text() на option.val() и в ссылке получать параметры с выбранного элемента в select.

Пробовал сделать так:

```
$('.target').change(function() {
    var text = $('.target').val();
$('span').text(text);

});
```

Текст меняется во всех span на странице, а надо только в текущем.

Comment: `$(this).prev().text(text);`

Comment: Уже ближе, но если поменять значение во втором или третьем select - текст span не изменяется. https://jsfiddle.net/4rs7mwpo/4/

Comment: @vitalmar надо писать в вопросе то, к чему вы что-то хотите применить и как у вас код выглядит, иначе конечно же предлагаемое решение может не сработать ибо нужен другой запрос..... всегда выкладывайте то, что есть и что нужно получить, а не вырванное из контекста

Comment: воит тут то тоже надо брать значение из текущего элемента а не из первого - `var text = $(this).val();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Помимо [prev](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA_%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%85_%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8), который для каждого из выбранных элементов находит предшествующий ему элемент (но только если он лежит на том же уровне иерархии DOM)  надо еще брать значение текущего селекта, на котором произошло событие. Это можно сделать с помощью `this`, т.е. указание на то, что надо взять значение в текущем контексте, т.е. на исполняемом элементе.

```js
$('.target').change(function() {
  // this указывает на конкретный элемент, 
  // на котором только что произошло событие 'change'
  var text = $(this).val(); 
  $(this).prev().text(text);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
  <span class="price">280</span>
  <select class="target">
    <option value="280" selected="selected">25см</option>
    <option value="380">33см</option>
  </select>
  <hr/>
</div>
<br/>
<div class="main">
  <span class="price">2801</span>
  <select class="target">
    <option value="2801" selected="selected">25см</option>
    <option value="3801">33см</option>
  </select>
  <hr/>
</div>
<br/>
<div class="main">
  <span class="price">28011</span>
  <select class="target">
    <option value="28011" selected="selected">25см</option>
    <option value="38011">33см</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо! Особенно за $(this)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский prev - cтрого предыдущий, в отличие от prevAll. У вас в тексте, на мой взгляд, неоднозначно

Comment: @splash58 а что неоднозначного? Там же по факту написано, что для каждого элемента, указанного в селекторе (в данном случае this - один элемент), будет выбран предшествующий ему (из селектора) элемент.... вроде все правильно и однозначно.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский не обращайте внимания, наверное, читать разучился от жары :)